# How to use a c++ application in web server?

Tags: c++, web-services, com

I am using a C++ console application in windows. I want to use this application in my website so that input is taken from client side which then invokes this application to process it and output will be forward to the web server. I have heard about **COM DLL** but don't know how to create it for my application.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm

Comment: What Web server are you going to use?  Apache? IIS? Are you planning to write your own?  What platform (Windows/Linux/BSD/BeOS)?

Comment: @Neil I am using Apache Tomcat on windows.

Comment: From the servlet call the externall app (C++): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should try creating a cgi script, depending on the needs of your application you should use FastCGI (which does not create an entire process context each time you call it).

- **CGI**

You should install an Apache Server and activate the cgi module(its activated by default commonly).
Then you can develop a c++ program, put the executable inside the configured CGI folder, give the correct permissions. This CGI script should make some kind of inter-process communication (it could be through socket or shared memory, the first one is easier).
I hope you know how a CGI script works in C/C++ + Apache, but its pretty straight forward, in summary you receive the environment inside stdin and put your answer to stdout.

- **FastCGI**

You can use apache, install the fastcgi module and create a thread (it could be inside your main loop too, but i dont recommend) inside your program and attach the apache server FastCGI module to your daemon.

Last but not least, you should run your daemon as a service.

> PS : There are some framework options(like cppcms and wt), but since
>   you already have the daemon written i thought it would be a pain in
>   the ass to change everything (of course, it depends on a lot of
>   things, like the complexity and size of your application).

Answer (score 5):

Use CGI: http://cgi.sourceforge.net/

How to take input from the client side?

```
getenv("QUERY_STRING")
```

How to forward output to the web server?

```
cout << "<html>\n";
```

Hello world CGI:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

   cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
   cout << "<html>\n";
   cout << "<head>\n";
   cout << "<title>Hello World - First CGI Program</title>\n";
   cout << "</head>\n";
   cout << "<body>\n";
   cout << "<h2>Hello World! This is my first CGI program</h2>\n";
   cout << "<p>REQUEST_METHOD = " << getenv("REQUEST_METHOD") << "</p>\n";
   cout << "<p>QUERY_STRING = " << getenv("QUERY_STRING") << "</p>\n";
   cout << "</body>\n";
   cout << "</html>\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: While the code suggestion might consitute an answer to the question, the mere code doea not provide explanation on why and how it is addressing the original question. So please add some explanations to provide more insight on what is needed to solve original problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are even several frameworks for developing them, including Wt, cppcms, CSP, and others. FastCGI's mainline implementation is in C, and directly supports several languages, including C++.

I recommend to use the C++ webtoolkit Wt (pronounced Witty), at http://www.webtoolkit.eu/.

This framework (with integrated application server) lets you design web applications in terms of widgets and signal/slot connections, and leaves much of the web cruft in the hands of the library. The resulting applications are object-oriented, strictly typed, and perfectly maintainable. The library autodetects the browser's capabilities and uses the proper way to render the site, avoiding browser bugs. Here is [an example of aplication using wt](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/browsercontrol/article.php/c15275/Wt-C-Web-Toolkit-Library-Lets-You-Write-ScriptingIndependent-Web-Apps.htm)

Also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417816/how-popular-is-c-for-making-websites-web-applications).

Comment: I already have an console c++ application that I want to connect with my web server. It will run in server but taking server local resources.

Answer (score 3):

My group just did that as a class project, we mostly used [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/#) as a network library, but we also used [curlpp](https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp) for some minor stuff. We hosted it on an Amazon EC2 instance setup as a windows server, and you are free to do the UI however you want really. It was a fairly simple project but taking that route was not as limiting as I thought it would be. Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

For high performance on Windows and IIS 6 you want to create an [ISAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525172(v=vs.90).aspx) dll; in IIS 7 you will want to create a [module](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview). Neither are particularly trivial and you will have to do a lot of reading.